# How to mark an item completed with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm playing around with [the Redux todo example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos).

I changed **/components/TodoList.js**, since I don't want to use the input field and the "Add todo" button, but I just want to have my own car data there. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Todo from './Todo'

const cars = [
  {text: 'Audi', id: 1},
  {text: 'Nissan', id: 2},
  {text: 'Mazda', id: 3},
]

const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {cars.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)

export default TodoList
```

How do I get the toggling to work (I mean marking the car completed: true || false)? 
In **/reducers/todos.js** I have the following:

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id,
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(todo =>
        (todo.id === action.id) 
          ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
          : todo
      )
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default todos
```

**This part is clearly wrong:**

```
(todo.id === action.id)
```

I tried various things, but can't get the toggling (completed: true || false) to work on the "Audi", "Nissan", and "Mazda". I also tried at looking at other questions, but couldn't find a solution.

How do I mark the cars "completed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you're using your hard-coded list of cars, and not the state returned via Redux.  It doesn't matter what you dispatch; the `cars` variable is never updated, and thus never receives the toggled state.

The solution here is to use that list of cars in your initial Redux state.

```
const initialState = [
  { text: 'Audi', id: 1, completed: false },
  { text: 'Nissan', id: 2, completed: false },
  { text: 'Mazda', id: 3, completed: false }
]

const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_TODO':
    return [
      ...state,
      {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
    return state.map(todo =>
      (todo.id === action.id) 
        ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
        : todo
    )
  default:
    return state
  }
}

export default todos
```

Comment: You'll need to update `nextTodoId` as well. Alternatively you could bootstrap the initial list of cars in `componentWillMount` or the constructor by dispatching the `addTodo` action (thus avoiding the initial state and reset nextTodoId).